# Set out filter for Action_Pick Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using `ACTION_PICK` intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONTACT);
```

However, I want to send a filter such that the list does not shows any contact number that does not have any name.

Similarly I want to filter out to show only those contacts that have got a number specific to a country code. For e.g. show only contacts that starts with 61.

Anything possible here?